# 0xdbe Download new version has Expired

Tags: datagrip

[image]

I download new version ,but can't start work and tell me download new version.so ，
How can I deal with it?

Comment: DownLoad Date : January 10, 2016

Comment: The product has now been officially relased as [JetBrains DataGrip](http://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)

Answer (score 0):

0xDBE EAP program is over, IDE is now called DataGrip. Please download latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/download.